# Installing CDash - missing install.php

Tags: laravel, installation, cdash

When I install CDash as per:
https://github.com/Kitware/CDash/blob/master/docs/install.md

I'm supposed to be redirected to install.php.
However, I get a 503 Service Unavailable.
If I explicitly type in /install.php, I get a 404, which makes sense, as the file doesn't exist. I'm new to laravel, maybe its some sort of composite file generated on the fly? or it should exist and I've missed something in the install? I'm stumped
I'm using:
nginx/1.24.0:void linux (kernel 6.1.29_1):mariadb v10.5.10-MariaDB-debug:php 8.2.4

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

I installed the CDash application as specified in
https://github.com/Kitware/CDash/blob/master/docs/install.md
When complete, I'm supposed to be automatically redirected to /install.php